Who abducted Indra's wife Sachi?
When Ravana came to abduct Sita, Sita told Ravana that
Valmiki Ramayana, Aranyakandam, Chapter 48 (last part)

One can breathe on this earth carrying away Indra's wife, Sachi—but stealing me, the wife of Rāma, no body shall be able to live in peace. O Rākshasa, it might be possible for one to live on this earth treating contemptuously the wife of the holder of thunder-bolt, but insulting me none shall escape the hands of Death even if he drinketh nectar.

My question is did Ravana ever abduct Indra's wife Sachi? Or has anybody else ever abducted or tried to abduct Indra's wife?
Reference -
Valmiki Ramayana translated by M N Dutt
